# Why is Runtime Error popping up?

Tags: c++, runtime-error, fork

Can Somebody please help me in this? Why is Runtime Error popping up?  Thanks in advance:) I am not very good with C++.

```
   #include <iostream>
    #include<sys/types.h>
    #include<sys/ipc.h>
    #include<sys/shm.h>
    #include<string.h>
    #include<unistd.h>
    #define KEY 123456
    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        int shmid=shmget(KEY, 128, 0666);
        char* addr1=(char*)shmat(shmid, 0, 0);
        strcpy(addr1, "Hello");

        int pid=fork();
        if(pid!=0)
        {
            char* addr2=(char*)shmat(shmid,0,0);
            std::cout<<"\n"<<addr1;
            std::cout<<"\n"<<addr2;
            sleep(2);
            std::cout<<"\n"<<addr1;
            std::cout<<"\n"<<addr2;
            int rval=shmdt(addr2);
            std::cout<<"\n"<<addr1;
            std::cout<<"\n"<<addr2;
        }
        else
        {
            strcpy(addr1, "World");
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Can Somebody please help me in this? Why is Runtime Error popping up?  Thanks in advance:) I am not very good with C++.
Can Somebody please help me in this? Why is Runtime Error popping up?  Thanks in advance:) I am not very good with C++.
Sorry I had to do this to make the content larger.

Comment: Can you show us the compiler errors?

Comment: You do "std::cout<<"\n"<<addr2" in the parent process *after* calling "shmdt(addr2)".  That's undefined behaviour.

Comment: What runtime error? How can I know what error you get if you don't post the exact message here?

Comment: I compiled it using online IDE of https://www.codechef.com/ide @KingsInnerSoul

Comment: I compiled it using online IDE of codechef.com/ide @rlam12

Comment: That is the whole purpose of this code. I want to see the behaviour of this code after detaching the region from the virtual address as to what will be printed. @G.M.

Comment: As stated in my first comment it's [undefined behaviour](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) -- anything can happen.